# Git shows changes in freshly cloned repo and won't let me add / commit these files

Tags: git

I've just cloned a *big* git repository (ubuntu-precise Linux kernel), and git is showing me several changes (13 files).

I tried `git stash`, `git checkout -- .` and `git add .`, but the changes stay there, `not staged for commit`.

`git diff` shows *real* changes to files. I mean, my problem is not simply related to encoding problems or line endings.

I am running `git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)` on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Mind showing the diff?

Comment: Here's the diff : https://gist.github.com/Duhemm/9294734 Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be similar to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/HgVrBEaLgmQ)

> there are two files in that directory which differ only in the case (IIRC the other one is `xt_connmark.h`).
>
> **You cannot check out the Linux kernel on a filesystem which does not respect upper vs lower case**.

This should be a side-effect of the [HFS+, the Mac filesystem, which is usually configured to be case insensitive but case preserving.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22304)

Answer (score 0):

The solution below **didn't work** ! I've been able to checkout another branch, but unfortunately those changes appear once again (pretty sure those are the same)

> I turns out `git commit -am "..."` solved my problem.
>
> I somebody has an explanation to this problem I would be very happy to hear it !

Comment: Maybe try `git reset --hard HEAD`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Mac's HFS is by default case insensitive.

For simple solution, you can create a mountable disk image by:

`hdiutil create -type SPARSE -fs 'Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+' -size 40g ~/git.dmg`

Then mount this image by `open git.dmg`.

Then clone git repo in the mounted volume.